# Adding an onSubmit function in Semantic-ui validation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

Im upload files with a form so when the submit button is pressed, I need to inform the user with a loading button. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713569/semantic-ui-onsuccess-callback-called-even-when-form-validation-fails) seems to not work.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.ui.form').form({
  fields: {
    input1: {
      identifier: 'input1',
      rules: [{
        type: "empty",
        prompt: "input1 - This field is required"
      }]
    },
    input2: {
      identifier: 'input2',
      rules: [{
        type: "empty",
        prompt: "input2 - This field is required"
      }]
    }
  },
  onSuccess() {
    //$('.submit.button').addClass('loading')
    console.log('Form submitting...')
  }
});
```

I've left out the html just to focus on the JS. Removing on `onSuccess()`, will submit the form but not with the `onSuccess()` in. Am I going this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a callback for onSuccess with form submit.

You should grab the values from your form and then use $.post and use the success callback.

```
$('.ui.form').submit(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url/to/server.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {
      // callback code here
    },
  });

})
```